# AWS Load Balancer Rules: Forward path with query parameters to Target Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elb

I'm using CloudFront and ALB to forward a path from my main domain to a target group with a registered instance. Everything is working fine, but I need to forward query parameters in the URL.

Right now
`https://mymaindomain.com/my_registered_rule/`
is correctly being forwarded to the corresponding container

But when doing `https://mymaindomain.com/my_registered_rule/?query=1234` The query is ignored.

Is there any way around this?

this is how I'm doing the forwarding:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "the query is ignored"? Are you saying the query string is not being forwarded to the target? Are you absolutely sure the issue is at the load balancer and not the container?

Comment: @MarkB I think so, when I check the nginx logs on the container instance the request that I get from "Amazon CloudFront" is /my_registered_rule/ not /my_registered_rule/?query=1234...  [06/Sep/2022:17:50:35 +0000] "GET /my_registered_rule/ HTTP/1.1" 500 156 "-" "Amazon CloudFront"

Comment: I'm not sure Nginx logs the query string by default.

Comment: Yes it does, I found the solution, it was in Cloudfront, I'll answer the question

Answer (score 1):

The problem wasn't at the Load Balancer level but on the cloudfront distribution behavior cache side.
I had to enable the queries on the legacy cache setting like this:

[image]